# php simple_xml xpath issue for gpx file

Tags: php, xpath, gps, simplexml, gpx

I try to get the lat and lon's from a gpx file (GPS XML).
When I do (snippet): $res = $xml->xpath('//*');
   I get the full content returned.
When I try to narrow down like this: $res = $xml->xpath('//rte');
   I get nothing: array(0) { }.
   Even when the tag(s) exists.
Actually whatever I try to fill in after // other then * it returns nothing. Have been trying for hours...

Comment: Can you post a sample of your XML?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the correct namespace (Maybe "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"?) in your node test.

As example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($URI);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gpx', 'http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1');
$res = $xml->xpath('//gpx:rte');
```

Comment: This works. Now I start to understand what's going on...
thanks a lot for the quick reply.
-Patrick